# How Could One Automatically Create New Page When User Registers

Tags: php, html, authentication

I want to automatically create a webpage for each user when they register. I finally found an article on [creating files using PHP here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_create.asp)

It states that

> The `fopen()` function is also used to create a file. Maybe a little confusing, but in PHP, a file is created using the same function used to open files.

So I placed this code in between my working registration code in an attempt to create a file when a user is registered:

```
$myfile = fopen("users/$Username", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
```

But I'm getting this error message:

> Warning: fopen(users/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /home/mir092/public_html/Register.php on line 17
>   Unable to open file!

Comment: `$Username` seems to be null or empty per the *error message*. `users/` is a directory.

Comment: Is your intention to create a profile page for each user?

Comment: Yes, Its my intention to have a profile page for each user. For instance, when we registered for this site, we each got a page, e.g. mine is http://stackoverflow.com/users/5524183/matthew-ralston

Comment: @MatthewRalston, it can't be done in that way. Use MySQL for storing user data. Create a new php file named `user-profile.php` which accepts `$_GET['id']` and mask the ugly URL using `.htaccess` pretty SEO friendly URLs.